# What is a WTF Condition?

Tags: settings, developer-options

If you go to the developer tools menu in Settings, then tap Launch Tools and open Bad Behavior,  there's an option to "Report a WTF Condition". What is a WTF Condition? Why would an app report one?

Comment: What phone or custom ROM are you using? There's no such option in the standard developer optiohs.

Comment: @DanHulme nightly builds of CyanogenMod 11. toro.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In android development there are different logging levels. For example, there is `Log.v` for verbose, `Log.e` for level error, `Log.w` for level warn. All these are visible in logcat during development.

Then there is `Log.wtf` which is like `Log.e` except it has level Assert which may actually terminate the program depending on the system. Ideally, this should *never* happen in your app.

Sidenote: `wtf` stands for "what a terrible failure".

Android docs on this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: And there I thought WTF stood for something else... (Worse Than Failure, of course)

Comment: I'm sure they spent some time coming up for an appropriate expansion for that acronym. ;)

Comment: What the F*** does WTF stand for? :)

Comment: What The Fudge maybe?

Comment: Quite likely what it formerly stood for.